# Asp.net Datalist Session value

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and I'm trying to put a Session variable in the datalist headertemplate and item template, but can't seem to make it work, any ideas?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer Interval="1000" Enabled="false" OnTick="UpdateChatTable1" runat="server" ID="Timer2"></asp:Timer>
        <asp:DataList ID="ChatTable1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server"
            Style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 400px;z-index:3" CssClass="tbl">
            <HeaderTemplate><asp:Label ID="ChatTitle" Text='<%#Eval(Session["user"].ToString())%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>:</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="chatTable1Item" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="senderID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sender") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer2" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If yes, include it in your question

Comment: no there are no exceptions or errors

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    <HeaderTemplate><asp:Label ID="ChatTitle" Text='<%#Session["user"]%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>:</HeaderTemplate>
```

Notice Eval method is not used

Comment: i tried it, the result is that "<%Session["user"]%>: " is being displayed

Comment: Ensure you have `Text='<%#Session["user"]%>'`